# Function that converges to $\infty$ at every point

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

I was wondering whether there exists a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ that satisfies:
$$\text{For all } y\in\Bbb R: \lim_{x\to y} f(x)=\infty.$$

Intuitively it seems to me like this is impossible. But I don't see how to prove it.

By definition we would have
$$\forall y \in \Bbb R: \forall r \in \Bbb R_+: \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in (y-\delta, y+\delta)\setminus\{y\}: f(x)>r,$$
and not I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Wouldn't $\{x:f(x)\le n\}$ have to be a nowhere dense set? Doesn't Baire have something to say about that?

Comment: This may help: [Existence of a function whose limits go to infinity almost everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097092/existence-of-a-function-whose-limits-go-to-infinity-almost-everywhere).

Comment: Blumberg's Theorem shows that there is  no such function. See https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Blumberg_theorem

Comment: Note there are pathological functions which satisfy this if $\lim$ is replaced with $\limsup$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such a function does not exist, because $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable and complete.

Let $A_n = \{x \in [0,1]: |f(x)| \leq n\}$. If $A_n$ was infinite, we could extract a strictly monotone subsequence $x_k$ converging to some $x \in [0,1]$ by compactness. 
Since $|f(x_k)| \leq n$ we have $\lim_{x_k\rightarrow x}f(x_k) \neq \infty$, which violates the assumption.
Thus, $A_n$ is has to be finite, but then $[0,1] = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ can only contain countably many points, which is a contradiction.